# How to use the pattern に行く to express several purposes

Tags: grammar

I was reviewing the `stem + に行く` like for example:

> うちへ食べに行く.

But, how about expressing several purposes like:

> I'm going home to eat and take a shower.

I'm not really sure how to add several purposes with this pattern, or if its even possible.

Is the next example even grammatically correct?

> うちへ食べとシャワーを浴びに行く。

Thank you beforehand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> うちに食べに帰る。/ ｛ごはん/お昼etc｝を食べにうちに帰る。
>   I'm going home to eat (supper, lunch etc).
>   うちにシャワーを浴びに帰る。/ シャワーを浴びにうちに帰る。
>   I'm going home to take a shower.

sound good, but...

> うちに食べとシャワーを浴びに帰る。
>   うちに食べてシャワーを浴びに帰る。
>   食べてシャワーを浴びにうちに帰る。*

sound incorrect/unnatural.
<sub>(*食べてシャワーを浴びにうちに帰る would be understood as "I will eat (something/supper) and go home to take a shower.")</sub>

> I'm going home to eat and take a shower.

I can't think of a way to say it using 「連用形+に+行く/帰る」. I would instead say...

> うちに帰って、｛ごはん/お昼/お昼ご飯/晩ご飯etc｝を食べてシャワーを浴びる/浴びてくる。*

<sub>(*You'd use ～てくる when you're going to come back to where you are after you eat lunch and take a shower.)</sub>

Comment: 食べたりシャワーを浴びたりしにうちに帰る、なら一応通じますかね？意味も若干変わるし少し言いにくくはあるけど…

Comment: @Darius そうですね、いいと思います。「～たり～たりしに…」は使えると思います。

Comment: わかりました、本当にありがとうございました